# Get header row value from TODAY() found in multi-D array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Multi-D array of dates (say "F3:AO21"), and want to use TODAY() to find which column in that array matches TODAY(). Once found, to return the value of the matching column, but always row 2.

No matter what column TODAY() is found, the value returned should always be: Column = column of TODAY() found; Row = row 2.

Thanks,
Jason.

Comment: better to show a sample set of data at least showing how your dates are ordered in that range. also please confirm if all dates in the range are unique?

Answer (score 2):

Use AGGREGATE inside an INDEX:

```
=INDEX(2:2,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(F3:AO21)/(F3:AO21=TODAY()),1))
```

[image]