# How to search for multiple values across columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a table (Table 1) with multiple names per row i.e. Column Structure is (Unique ID, Name 1, Name 2, Name 3, etc). I then have another table (Table2) which is just a list of names in one column (Name x, Name y, Name z, etc). I am trying to identify which rows in Table 1 have a column with a name in Table2 and then return whichever name is matching. It does not matter if there are multiple matches, I only care if there is a match.

My current thinking is to use the Index(match) function, but I am unsure if there is a way to input the list from table 2 into the "Lookup Value" spot of the match portion. Does anyone know if this is possible or if there is another way to get what I am looking for?

Comment: Cbar, where do you want the results returned to? Do you want formulas or VBA?

Comment: are you talking something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065221/get-header-row-value-from-today-found-in-multi-d-array/67065266#67065266

Comment: I think possible. Post some sample data to your post. What version of Excel do you have?